# Masonry Container Grid Height Issue

Tags: html, css, masonry

I have used masonry with infinite scroll in angular, so when the user reaches the end of the products listing, a div is appended

```
 <div class="row top10">
    <ul class="productsList" masonry load-images="false" infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-disabled="endReached" infinite-scroll-immediate-check="false" >
        <li class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 masonry-brick" ng-repeat="product in products" images-loaded="productsImagesLoadedEvents">
           // markup of the tile
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="row bottom10" ng-show="endReached">
    <div class="col-xs-12 thatsAllFolks">
        That's all folks!
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the same is :

```
    .thatsAllFolks {
      background: #f5f5f5;
      text-align: center;
      color: #aaa;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

I'm facing this issue in safari only that the container of the masonry grid is having the wrong height which is why the that's all folks div is appearing on little above from the bottom. How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: try putting `overflow: hidden` or clearfix on the container. If that doesn't work it could be happening because you are initiating masonry before the images have a change to load

Answer (score 2):

Use ImageLoaded js lib to fix this:

https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

It's accure because the grid created before all images completely loaded. so this lib from the same author fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Masonry and I see on the screenshot of the questions it might be the same issue. If the `<img>` tags do not have a width or height set (not necessarily as tag attributes, but alternatively as CSS attributes), the element when are added in the DOM are going to be evaluated with the wrong dimensions, because the grid items are going to be taller after the images are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `break-inside-avoid` tailwind class for safari browser !!